# C# bot Auto send a message if the time detect is set

Tags: c#, time, botframework

I dont know how to ask, but this is what i want, i have a set time.

```
int nyhours = 14;
int mymin = 00;
int mysec = 00;
TimeSpan stime = new TimeSpan(nyhours, mymin, mysec);
TimeSpan timeNow = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan trimmedTimeNow = new TimeSpan(timeNow.Hours, timeNow.Minutes, timeNow.Seconds);
```

and i want to chat automatically in the skype. This is my code.

```
if (stime == trimmedTimeNow)
{
  await context.PostAsync($"Good day guys please what is the status of your work? :)");
}
```

that code is not working. How to fix that codes? please help. Did I make it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Auto send a message if the time detect is set

You seem to want to set a timer or reminder to notify the user when the time arrives via your bot. Your bot would not compare current time with specified time every second, so it might not fulfill the condition `stime == trimmedTimeNow`.

To achieve your requirement, in your bot application, you can try to extract data from the user's message, such as `conversationId`, `channelId`, `Recipient.Id`, `ServiceUrl` etc, and save the data in some store. And then you can use and run an Azure Function or WebJob to send messages with attached recipient info.

In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-concept-templates#proactive-bot), you can find more detailed information about proactive bot, you can refer to it to implement a proactive bot based on your scenarios and requirements.

Comment: what about sending message into group? not only in one user but for the group chat? is that possible?

Comment: Groups on which channel?

Answer (score 0):

As @Fei-Han mentioned in his answer above. You will have to save the conversation properties.

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

When you want to send the message create a message object

```
// Create a new message.
IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();

// Set message object properties
..
..
//create a bot connector
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(ServiceURL));
//send message
await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```